# Export Azure Cost Analysis Data into CSV using ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Is it possible to download the cost analysis data (Cost Usage Report) of all resources in Azure using an ARM Template. Can it be downloaded to a CSV file using an ARM template. Please share a sample template
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnfwn.png)

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail and provide the screenshot of what you want to get?

Comment: I'm trying to use an ARM template to deploy the Export Feature of Azure cost Management. I did create a JSON file to perform the action. But it fails to validate as the Resource Type is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my research, we cannot use the arm template to export the data. Azure arm template does not provide resource type `Microsoft.CostManagement\Export`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/)

So if you want to export the data, I suggest you use Azure REST API to do that. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/exports/create-or-update) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/tutorial-export-acm-data?tabs=azure-powershell)

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/exports/{exportName}?api-version=2020-06-01
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I used Azure REST API and implemented the same. Thanks for the feedback